# Fragment replacement errors

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to replace a fragment of mine but I'm unable to do so because of these error. However I already have these imports, hence I've no idea what's wrong here.

**Error 1**

```
Error:(73, 96) error: incompatible types
required: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
found:    android.app.FragmentTransaction
```

**Error 2**

```
Error:(72, 48) error: incompatible types
required: Fragment
found:    FragmentMap
```

**Imports**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

**Fragment replacing code**

```
Fragment newFragment = new FragmentMap();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

[image]

**Latest screenshot**
[image]

Comment: change `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()` and letme know if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Error 1**

```
Error:(73, 96) error: incompatible types
required: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
found:    android.app.FragmentTransaction
```

change `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()` and it should work.

> `getSupportFragmentManager()` is used when you are using support lib (your case). and `getFragmentManager()` is used when not using support lib.

For **Error 2**

```
Error:(72, 48) error: incompatible types
required: Fragment
found:    FragmentMap
```

So to replace a fragment use this :

```
Fragment newFragment = new FragmentMap();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

`newFragment` is the one to be replaced but throwing an error.

> Make sure the `FragmentMap` or any other fragment to be replaced, is extended by Fragment class (of support lib and not the normal one, because `newFragment` is an object of `Fragment` from support lib) using `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` and **not** `import android.app.Fragment;`

Comment: trying to replace the master fragment instead of the detail fragment

Comment: It does help but a new error appears. Please check my latest screenshot

Comment: is your `FragmentMap` extending `Fragment` from support lib?

Comment: Ya!! make sure in your `FragmentMap` you using  `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` for importing `Fragment`